# NVM - Nodist doesn't match any version - WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm, yarnpkg

I'm working on a project using WebStorm. Yesterday I installed nvm & nodist for manage multiple version of node. Today starting my project (*both on yarn start and npm start*) I've got this error.

> Sorry, there's a problem with nodist. Couldn't resolve node version spec %s: %s 11.13.0 Couldn't find any matching version

I've tried to fix reinstalling the node 11 version but the errors is still here.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you share your package.json file please ? I don't see any version tagged 11.13.0 in the github page of nodist...

Comment: do you have Node 11.13.0 installed? Also, does `npm start` work if you run it in your system terminal, outside of the IDE?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. I had Node 11.13.0 installed. First I updated node by Windows installer to 12.15.0, but `node --version` still returned 11.13.0. Installed nvm, it detected 11.13.0 and asked if it should be managed by nvm (responded with Yes). Installed 12.15.0 by doing `nvm install 12.15.0` and `nvm use 12.15.0`. After that above error occurred.

Executing the command `nodist` gave the following output:

```
  (x64)
No builds installed, yet.
```

Which led me to believe that nvm uses nodist, but nodist doesn't know about both 11.13.0 and 12.15.0.

To fix it I simply did the following:

1. Uninstall the manually installed 12.15.0 (Windows uninstaller)
2. Execute `nvm uninstall 11.13.0` (resulted in failure: asked me to manually remove the folder in the nodist directory, which I did)
3. Execute `nodist 12.15.0` to install node 12.15.0 again via nodist.
4. Execute `nodist use 12.15.0` to use this version.

Problem solved! Here are the complete logs.

```
C:\Users\name>nvm install 12.15.0
Downloading node.js version 12.15.0 (64-bit)...
Complete
Creating C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\nvm\temp

Downloading npm version 6.13.4... Complete
Installing npm v6.13.4...

Installation complete. If you want to use this version, type

nvm use 12.15.0

C:\Users\name>nvm use 12.15.0
[...]

C:\Users\name>node --version
Sorry, there's a problem with nodist. Couldn't resolve version spec %s: %s 11.13.0 Couldn't find any matching version

C:\Users\name>nodist
  (x64)
No builds installed, yet.

C:\Users\name>nvm

Running version 1.1.7.
[...]
```

Continued in Powershell:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> nodist 12.15.0
12.15.0
Installing 12.15.0
 12.15.0 [===============] 28127/28127 KiB 100% 0.0s
Installation successful.
PS C:\Windows\system32> nodist use 12.15.0
12.15.0
12.15.0
PS C:\Windows\system32> node --version
v12.15.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurred because I installed `Nodist` later. So I had to do

```
nodist use 20.10.0
```

to run my node and npm under nodist.